# Generate Equivalent DLL from ELF shared object

Tags: windows, dll, shared-libraries, elf

I have some source for a shared object that I want to run on a *nix platform. However I need to measure that code using a utility that only exists for Windows, and expects a DLL.

In particular this utility measures the virtual memory occupied by the DLL just after loading.

Is there a way, or better yet a tool, which can generate the equivalent (in this case meaning results in an identical loaded library) DLL given a .so?

I realize that the code cannot be run, but I just need it to load so I can measure it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any tools to tell you how much *virtual* memory and ELF object will occupy. You can simply add together the sizes of `PT_LOAD` segments (which you can in `readelf -l foo.so` output). Dynamic linker will `mmap` *exactly* these segments, with exactly these sizes, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I'm not measuring the _amount_ of virtual memory, but another property entirely.

Comment: @thunt Your question says "this utility measures the virtual memory occupied by the DLL just after loading". If you want a meaningful answer, you should ask *precisely* what you want to measure.

Comment: Ah yes, you've hit upon exactly the problem. I don't know exactly what it's measuring; It's proprietary software. However, I need to use it's measurement to work with some hardware.

Comment: @thunt I am afraid your question makes very little sense then: "how can I convert an ELF into a DLL in such a way that this proprietary tool, which I have no idea what it measures, will produce some meaningful answer?" Given this question, the answer is clearly 42.